# Cannot upload large file x>1GB in ASP.NET CORE 6 RAZOR PAGES

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i have been looking for a way to upload a large files to my server.
My form works for small files x<30MB.
This is my form:

```
    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">
         <center><b>Dodaj obrazek</b></center>
      </div>
<div class="card-body">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="mb-3">
     <input type="file" asp-for="Gallery.Upload" class="form-control"  />
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using IFormFile

```
 [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }
```

I have been trying many scenarios like declaring RequestFormLimit before SiteModel or before Method:

```
 [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]
public class SiteModel : PageModel

    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
```

but still got nothing.

//UPDATE
I have added this to my Program.cs

```
    builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(conf =>
{
    conf.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    conf.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    conf.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
});
```

and this before SiteModel

```
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
```

and now i can upload only up to 100 MB, but i want to make it larger, like 4GB limit per one upload..

How can i change limit size?

Comment: What sort of response do you get when up upload the file? Are you using another program to host the application, such as IIS? Is this website behind a load balancer?

Comment: gnur2171 This is website behind a load balancer. Check update!

Comment: What error do you get? To upload large files you should avoid caching them in memory and use efficient transfer, not increase the limits.

Comment: I do not get any response back, my site is blank and no errors or anything

Comment: I think you could refer this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#stream-was-too-long-1

Answer (score 1):

After updating an older app to .net6 we ran into the same issue, and also tried all the things you have tried. It wasn't until a web.config was added back to the project that allowed the large upload to succeed. Here is all that was required:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration>   
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>                   
</system.webServer>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For.Net Core 6 and Razor Pages, we have some tips in Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

In Program.cs, they included the file limits as an option targeting the page that performs the upload:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => 
{
options.Conventions
    .AddPageApplicationModelConvention("/[your cshtml page name with no extension]",
        model =>
        {
            model.Filters.Add(
            new RequestFormLimitsAttribute()
            {
                // Set the limit to 256 MB
                ValueLengthLimit = 268435456,
                MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 268435456,
                MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 268435456
            });
           // model.Filters.Add(
           //     new RequestSizeLimitAttribute(268435456));
        });
});
```

In the documentation, they just added MultipartHeadersLengthLimit, but I included other limits you would be interested in changing too.

In your page model include:

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 268435456)]
public class YourPageNameModel : PageModel
{ ...}
```

Note that to follow their example, you must update the FileHelper.cs with the proper file signature if you are trying to upload a different extension. Otherwise, the page will return an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security + optimization feature. By default there is a limit on just how much content(quantity and quality) you can move per Payload. For .net core according to [this article](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/612cf2d1-5b3d-40eb-a5ff-924005955a62.aspx), it is about 25MB.

Depending on how you want to host, you could change this limit to suit your case.

You could add a web.config file to the project and add the code bellow.

```
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

you could also follow the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestformlimitsattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0)(This is for MVC, but it serves well).

Will that be enough? No. Due to the TCP/IP & IEEE Standard on Network structure, if you do not have an open pipeline, transfering large files can be a chore without good network. it can easily break.

I would advice you to also try working on compressed files. This [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compressing-and-decompressing-files-in-chash#:%7E:text=Compressing%20and%20Decompressing%20files%20in%20C%23%201%20Compress,same%20the%20GZipStream%20class.%20...%204%20Example%20) compresses file into a Zip.

```
 using(var compress = new GZipStream(outputFile, 
        CompressionMode.Compress, false)) 
 {
     byte[] b = new byte[inFile.Length];
     int read = inFile.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
     while (read > 0) 
     {
        compress.Write(b, 0, read);
        read = inFile.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
     }
 }.
```

If you are dealing with Videos, however, i will advice against compressing to Zip or Rar. this is because videos are already very much compressed. you could however "traspose & transform", meaning that you could covert from an Avi to an Mkv. Sometimes, this process could me loss in data and quality.